# Is it possible to build iphone project by Gradle?

Tags: iphone, gradle

I have an iPhone project and I build it by XCode.
I also have an Android project and build it by Gradle.

Is it possible to build the iPhone project also by Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with building iPhone projects, but if you can build the project via commandline commands, then you can also make Gradle call those commands using tasks of type `Exec`.

As far as I know there is no dedicated iPhone project support in Gradle to date, but you might suggest it on the Gradle forums.